# Mat-input no cambia el color del placeholder

Tags: angular, angular-material

Tengo un problema con respecto a cambiar el color de los *placeholder* en un componente:

Una parte de los template HTML es así:

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
<mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid">
<input  matInput placeholder="Orden" formControlName="Orden" readonly>
<mat-error> Orden <strong>es obligatorio.</strong> </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Y lo que uso en SCSS es lo siguiente:

```scss
::ng-deep .mat-input-element::placeholder{
    color: green;
}
```

Lo que busco es esto:

[image: foto2]

Pero no logro cambios, sigue manteniéndose en un color gris cuando realmente lo quiero en verde; espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar el color tienes que aplicarlo en el *label*, seria de la siguiente forma:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label {
    color: #F60 !important;
}
```

Siendo **`#F60`** color naranja, tendría que verse algo así :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O aplicando un verde se vería así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Para el caso en el que necesites aplicarlo en un solo input seria de la siguiente forma:

En el HTML:

```
<mat-form-field id='mi-componente'>
    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Orden">
</mat-form-field>
```

En el CSS:

```
#mi-componente::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label {
    color: #F60 !important;
}
```

Comment: Es correcto, la solución funciona, sin embargo esto se aplica para todo el proyecto y no solo para el componente actual; mi solución para que se aplique solo en el componente fue hacer uso de un `<mat-label style="color:green"></mat-label>`.  De todas formas, gran respuesta.

Comment: También podrías darle un id para especificar, agregaré un ejemplo utilizando un id. Aunque la solución que le diste es muy valida. ;)

Comment: No tenía ni idea jaja te daría doble respuesta pero no se puede jaja un saludo, gracias nuevamente.